# What is the safest php method to check that a string is a number?

Tags: php, null, is-empty

I checked various method (is_numeric, isset), but I'm not sure built methods are safe in any case.

I need it to work even if the variable to check is:

- an empty string
- null/undefined or whatever invalid state possible

Comment: Does [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) work for you?

Comment: like filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)? And is safe in each case? I think part of the problem is I don't really know what are there possibile cases...

Comment: Safe? What do you mean by 'safe'?

Comment: `is_numeric` is a safe function, because just return true or false.

Comment: 'Safe', Jay, means I can be 100% sure it won't throw blocking error if the variable passed to it has particular values, and about his behaviour in cases like an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this covers all your cases. `is_numeric` seems safe enough.

```
$values = [
    0,
    -3232323,
    423432094823904832948234574072357589345789345789345791305432794827342365786345693453417846393,
    123232e43,
    '-1232132132',
    '023',
    'abcdefaf',
    '0xdeadbeef',
    '',
    null
];


foreach ($values as $val) {
    echo var_export($val, true);
    if (is_numeric($val))
        echo " is numeric\n";
    else
        echo " is NOT numeric\n";
}
```

Output:

```
0 is numeric
-3232323 is numeric
4.2343209482390483E+92 is numeric
1.23232E+48 is numeric
'-1232132132' is numeric
'023' is numeric
'abcdefaf' is NOT numeric
'0xdeadbeef' is NOT numeric
'' is NOT numeric
NULL is NOT numeric
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

maybe function is_numeric() will work for you
http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

all built-in functions are pretty safe

maybe try this code:

```
if (!empty($variable) && is_numeric($variable)) {...}
```

Comment: yep, the question was about this. How is_numeric behave in case of an empty string? There are values possible for a variable that result in throwing a blocking error if is_numeric is applied to it? Best option is to try, but I can't presently and I am not sure about all the possibile invalid states a php variable can have.

Comment: is_numeric() is pretty strait forward, but be careful with empty(), i.e. something what can be considered as not empty (like not empty string '0') will give true result while using empty() function

Comment: 'be careful'? Why? empty() has issues?

Comment: sorry, I have edited my comment, i.e. empty('0') will return true even if this in not like totally empty string. If You are dealing only with numbers it clear and it works as expected